# Find an automaton that recognizes this language

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

The exercise is copied literally, and asks to **find an automaton that recognizes the language described by the regular expression $a{(bab\vee a)}^\ast b$**.

I have no idea how to start.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Try RegEx -> NDFA -> DFA. Check this out for more details http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node9.html

Comment: @DiegoAterio thanks. I could draw [this automaton](https://imgur.com/a/oZ2fh), but I think it recognizes the language $abab\vee ab$. I do not know how to write it with the closure of Kleene because there is a disjunction in between. If there was no such disjunction, could I do a loop with $baba$, wich will be equivalent to $ba$?

Comment: I apologize for the mistake in the appointment of the name, @DiegoAsterio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This automaton should recognize strings that starts with $a$ and ends in $b$ which is easy to draw. $$\rightarrow s_0\stackrel{a}\rightarrow s_1\stackrel{b}\rightarrow s_2$$ where $s_2$ is the final state.

The middle part $(bab\vee a)^*$ is a finite length string made of $bab$ and $a$. This should be implemented in the state $s_1$ with self-loop labeled $a$ and for $bab$, $$s_1\stackrel{b}\rightarrow s_3\stackrel{a}\rightarrow s_4\stackrel{b}\rightarrow s_1.$$

**Edit:**

Image by @manooooh

[image]

Comment: Like [this](https://imgur.com/WQqKGqS)?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: Oh really? Thank you! $\ddot\smile$.